# The key pair 'AdvancedCFN' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I keep receiving this statement in an addition with a failure to create the cloud formation stacks:

> The key pair 'AdvancedCFN' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

When I delete the line `KeyName: AdvancedCFN` from the EC2 part of the Resources Section, the stack will build but then it raises I am running an old version of PHP. When I run: `yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd`, it still says the same thing, I insert this command after the `yum update -y command`

Here is the EC2 Section of the code:

```
EC2:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", AMALINUX] # Dynamic mapping + Pseudo Parameter
      InstanceType: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentSize, EC2]
      KeyName: AdvancedCFN
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap # good practice - always do this.
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2 --configsets wordpress --region ${AWS::Region}
            yum -y update
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a key pair with the name `AdvancedCFN`.
Check EC2 console > Network & Security > Key Pairs.

As a workaround, make `KeyName` a parameter.
Add the following parameter to the template:

```
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the ECS instances
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
```

You can the use the selected key as follows:

```
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
```